# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alpha' of undefined

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm quite new at Phaser/JavaScript so forgive me my newbie mistake but when the playGame function is triggered by clicking the button, the group (this.group) is supposed to fade out.

Yet I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alpha' of undefined.

I have almost the exact construction of code in a different JavaScript file and there it does seem to work. So I'm totally at a loss here.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

If you need more code to get a clue of the whole, just give me a shout.

The code:

```js
Main.Levels = function (game)
{
    this.game = game;
};

Main.Levels.prototype = 
{
    group: Phaser.Group,

    create: function()
    {
        this.group = this.game.add.group();
        this.group.alpha = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            var lvl = this.game.add.button(120 + (150 * (i % 3)), 270 + (150 * Math.floor(i / 3)), 'lvl' + (i+1));
            lvl.anchor = {x: 0, y: 0};
            lvl.orgWidth = 100;
            lvl.orgHeight = 100;
            lvl.name = i;

            lvl.onInputUp.add(this.playGame, lvl);

            this.group.add(lvl);
        }

        var fade = this.game.add.tween(this.group);
        fade.to({alpha: 1}, 300);
        fade.start();
    },

    playGame: function()
    {
        var fade = this.game.add.tween(this.group);
        fade.to({alpha: 0}, 300);
        fade.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried to replicate this error and was unable to do so (Phaser 2.4.4). To confirm, you get this error when you click on one of the buttons, correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the input callback of `lvl`, you're sending the callback function as the first parameter of `button.onInputUp.add()` and `lvl` as the second. The second parameter is the context of the callback, i.e. what will `this` refer to when calling it. Thus, when calling `playGame()`, it ends up that `this` is the level button, and it most likely doesn't have a `group` property. If you want to refer to the button's parent group (the group that the button is in), you can use `this.parent`.